# Access Ironpython dictionary from C#

Tags: c#-4.0, ironpython

I have dictionary defined in Ironpython script and I want to access this dictionary from my C# 
code. Can someone provide example code to achieve my requirement.

Sorry earlier I did not mention my problem statement with code.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Core")
import System
clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)
from System.Collections.Generic import Dictionary,List

def check(self):
    dict1 = Dictionary[str,str]
    dict1["a"] = "aa"
    dict2 = Dictionary[str,str]
    dict2["b"] = "bb"
    self[0] = dict1
#   self.Add(dict1)
    return self
```

C#

```
var runtime = Python.CreateRuntime();
dynamic test = runtime.UseFile("Test.py");


var myDictList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
var myDL = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
myDL = test.check(myDictList);
```

My objective is to operate(Add, remove from list) on List of Dictionary in python and send it back to C# where I can use it further.
What I want is either create a list of dictionary in python or in C# and use it in both( python and C#) the places.
How can I do so.

Comment: Supplying code with your efforts would make others help you better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Utils;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime;
using IronPython;
using IronPython.Hosting;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ScriptEngine pyEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
            ScriptScope pyScope = pyEngine.CreateScope();
            ScriptSource pyScript = pyEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}");
            CompiledCode pyCompiled = pyScript.Compile();
            pyCompiled.Execute(pyScope);
            IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary d = pyScope.GetVariable("d");
            Console.WriteLine(d.get("a"));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Should give you the first value for key 'a'. Hope this gets you going.
Possibly there are one or two includes too many.

Comment: Python dictionaries and C# dictionaries only share their names. For instance you can't have mixed types in C#. What's wrong with using  `IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary` as data type? You can use `pyScope.SetVariable` to set data as well as you can get data.

Comment: In python I am writing a parser which will take file path as input and create a list of dictionary of parsed item. Then I want to use parse data in C#. So I don't think pyScope.SetVariable or pyScope.GetVariable will help me because in C# I am not modifying anything I am just going to use the parsed content.

Comment: Have you tried my little code snipplet? I did use CreateScriptSourceFromString but you could also take a python script file as input. d is the dictionary. It has entries a:1 b:2 and c:3. I accessed a and got 1. Isn't this exactly what you wanted?
Also as an alternative you could use Xml.Serializer to serialize your dictionary and read it back in C# again. This will overcome the incompatibility between python dictionary and generic dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(self):
    dict1 = Dictionary[str,str]()
    dict1["a"] = "aa"
    dict2 = Dictionary[str,str]()
    dict2["b"] = "bb"
    self[0] = dict1
    #   self.Add(dict1)
    return self
```

attention  the ().