# How to pass C# Dictionary to Python and How can we get the same dictionary in python understandable format?

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

I am creating dictionary in C# like below.

```
IDictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>(); // C# Code
dict.Add(1,"One");
dict.Add(2,"Two");
dict.Add(3,"Three");
```

Now how can i pass this 'dict' variable to python understandable format (python understand dictionary format).Or any other solution.

Basically i have to pass dictionary kind of thing to python from C# to get data in python.

Comment: How are your projects connected?

Comment: I'd see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16282446/ - It lays out how they are different types, but you can access either from either "side" of the divide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use serialization using standard format. For example JSON.
[Json.NET serialization for C#](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm). And pass the string to python. In the python the should be another library to deserialize the string. ([This is the first link found while Googling "Python read JSON"](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-parse-data-from-json-into-python))

It is not the fastest way, but it works.

Comment: Hey MianenCZ, i used it but its giving me error of 'System can not found the file specified' when using this line of code , string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);

Comment: You have to add nugget package Newtonsoft.JSON